# Chrome Extension: Alarm triggering before it's time

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-chrome-extension

What I'm trying to accomplish is to trigger an alarm at a specific time from a list of times from 00:00 to 23:00.

For example, I want to trigger an alarm at 2 AM but when I use *Date.setUTCHours(2,0,0,0)* the alarm also triggers at 3 AM, 2 PM and 3 PM.

Alarm code:

```
chrome.alarms.clear("resetDailyValue");
chrome.alarms.create("resetDailyValue", {
        when: new Date().setUTCHours(resetTimeList.value, 0, 0, 0)
    });
```

*resetTimeList.value* - is the value the user can choose, from a list, to trigger the alarm

Comment: The only explanations are 1) it's a bug in Chrome, 2) you have set several alarms

Comment: Now that you mention it, I forgot to say this. Before I create a new alarm with the new time I always clear the alarm with the name "resetDailyValue".

Comment: Shouldn't matter - having the same id overwrites the alarm. You can check via chrome.alarms.getAll(console.log)

Comment: Just found out now that whenever I choose an hour in the past, the alarm gets cleared but If I choose one in the future the alarm is created. Example: Now, for me, is 16:37 and if I choose an hour between 00:00 and 16:00 the alarm gets cleared, but If I choose from 17:00 to 23:00, the alarm gets cleared and a new alarm is created.

Comment: resetTimeList.value is saved in chrome storage and I can see that it matches the value in the list. Maybe the problem is how I'm setting up the chrome.alarms.create().

Comment: I found out the problem... the method setUTCHours() or setHours() represents the number of milliseconds since epoch. If I want to set the alarm in the future, I need to add 24 to the hours of those methods. It's a bit more complex but that is the process.